# Django Admin--insert in the Filter Area and Tomorrow

Tags: django

I want to add an extra field in the filter area of the django-admin. Currently on date field, it is showing only Today Past 7 Days etc. I need also to have the Tomorrow field there. Is there a way to add this thing out there?

[image]

This is my admin:

```
class ParcareModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [ "email","user", "location",
                    "parking_on", "parking_off",  "venire", "plecare"]
    list_display_links = ["email", "user" ]
    list_editable = [ "parking_off", "parking_on","venire", "plecare"]
    list_filter = ["parking_on", "parking_off"]
    search_fields = ["location", "name"]
    date_hierarchy='parking_on'

    class Meta:
        model = Parcare

    # def email(self, obj):
    #     return obj.user.email

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        if not obj:
            user = request.user
            form.base_fields['user'].initial = user
            form.base_fields['email'].initial = user.email
        return form

admin.site.register(Parcare, ParcareModelAdmin)
```

Comment: Have you tried writing your custom filter for this and add the required options in the lookups method ? docs : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter

Comment: yeah man thanks! i got it with date_hierarchy='parking_on'. sometimes too much is info is too much!

Answer (score 0):

i got what i need with `date_hierarchy='parking_on'`